# An html online form debugger that transforms POST to GET

Tags: html, forms, post, get

I'm quite new to web development, but I'm trying to do some stuff in Python and so I need help.

Sometime ago, I went into a page to debug html forms that allowed me to change the **POSTs** to **GETs** in the **form request** and that really helped me get some info from html forms by just doing everything in the **URL** instead of having to make my program fill some forms.

Unfortunately I lost that page address and as much as I search in Google I cannot come up with it or anything similar again. Can you direct me to some links that do this?

I tried both Firebug in Firefox and developer tools in chrome, but they don't seem to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is probably quite basic for most people, but in Firebug, you just have to go into the "**NET**" tab, make the request and then analyse it and if you right click it and choose: "**Copy location with parameters**" you get the formatted URL ready to go, even when using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you have: `<form name="form1">`

You can this JavaScript:

```
document.form1.type="GET"
```

Use this in the page before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

The web developer tool bar for firefox will do this and much more:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

EDIT

You can also use firebug and inspect the form element and change it from POST to GET

Comment: Thank you. It does transform the POSTs to GETs, but it doesn't give me the called URL after.

Comment: Not to be the king of the obvious but cant you simply submit the form and it will be in the URL?

Comment: No. Not really, for instance in here: http://www.ctt.pt/feapl_2/app/open/tools.jspx?tool=0 you can submit the search and it remains with the same URL.

Comment: hmmm didnt follow the link, but that would make sense if it was submitted via JS